# MemoryError in loading Pybrain SupervisedDataSet

Tags: pybrain

I have training set of 2.4M data with 100K dimension.

When I load the data into `SupervisedDataSet` using `addSample()`, it calls `MemoryError` with only 130K data loaded.

Is there any method to load really big data onto `SupervisedDataSet`?